# Does GLFWwindow * window still points to valid glfw object?

Tags: c++, callback, glfw

I Initialize Glfw, create window and set scroll callback:

```
GLFWwindow * window = glfwCreateWindow (...);
glfwSetScrollCallback(window, GlScrollInput);
```

I have somewhere else function:

```
GlScrollInput (GLFWwindow * window, double x, double y){...}
```

Lets say after first usage I stored this pointer GLFWwindow * window. Is there a way to tell if this glfw window pointer is still valid(window is initialized and not destroyed or terminated)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep track of that yourself. In general, it's impossible for any C++ framework to check whether a raw pointer is still valid.

If the memory a pointer points to is freed, accessing its contents is now undefined behaviour. Any value could be in that section of RAM, thus any check you do will give you a random answer at best or segfault at worst.

TL;DR when working with pointers in C++ it's your responsibility to track the lifetime of your objects.

When a window in GLFW is destroyed, its contents will be freed, thus running into the above scenario.

Comment: Its not as much as check if the pointer is valid, Some classes selfmanage itself. For example with first born of the class there is created class that controls born elements and manage their resources giving methods to check them. Was hoping for that.